# What is the canonical age?

Tags: logical-deduction

Every `.` in this text is a digit and every sentence is correct :

> Captain was born in `. . . .`
>   He will be `. .` years old, a canonical age, in `. . . .`
>   In this text, There is only `.` different digits, each of them being used `.` times

**Can you find the canonical age?**

**EDIT**: "canonical" age here means "advanced" age. Sorry for that, wasn't aware this meaning was absent in english language!

**NOTE**: This was written in **1999**
**Source**: Hervé Lehning – Tangente-Pour la Recherche may 2000 (page 61)

Comment: "canonical" age is specifically 40yo and above. That's the age at which the church canon would allow a female housekeeper to live with a priest. A younger one would raise suspicion - and might face a higher risk of an embarassing pregnancy. I supposed the expression is merely used in Cathlic countries. Explanations in French: http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/un-age-canonique.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first answer:

> Captain was born in 1 9 4 2
>  He will be 4 6 years old, a canonical age, in 1 9 8 8
>  In this text, There is only 6 different digits, each of them being used 2 times

This is not exactly a canonical age though...

---

**EDIT :**
And my **BEST** answer:

> Captain was born in 1 9 1 3
>  He will be 9 3 years old, a canonical age, in 2 0 0 6
>  In this text, There is only 6 different digits, each of them being used 2 times

Now this is a canonical age!

Comment: your first answer is also invalidate by the presence of "He will be .. years old" so it has to be later than 1999

Comment: @Keelhaul - I'm curious, how did you go about solving this? I knew the factors of 12 would determine the number of unique numbers and their frequency, and also that it would be a '19xx' year. After that, I didn't know how to proceed. What did you do? Trial and error, or some guided approach?

Comment: Basically what you said, plus a bit of trial and error, suspecting the age would be in the 90ies there wasn't much room left.

Comment: How is this a canonical age?

Comment: Like OP said, "canonical age" means very old in french ("âge canonique"), but may have a different meaning in english. I'm inclined to think it's nothing more than a translation mistake, but being french myself I was lucky enough to understand what OP meant :)

Answer (score 4):

I got this one.

> Captain was born in `1 9 9 3`
>  He will be `1 3` years old, a canonical age, in `2 0 0 6`
>  In this text, There is only `6` different digits, each of them being used `2` times

How I achieve that?

> At first, I assume that the Captain was born in `1 9 A B` and will be on canonical age in `2 0 C D` because the script was written in **1999**.
>
>  We already have 4 different digits here, but writing `4` means we have 5 different digits. So there is a total of `6` different digits here, and each of them being used `2` times. (`5` is impossible because the number of `.` is not divisible by 5).
>
>  So now we have `1 9 A B` + `E F` = `2 0 C D`, and we know that `ABCDEF` can be `0169XX`. By some deduction, we can know that `0` can only replace `C`. And then, I was trying to put `A` = `9` and `E` = 1 the leaving `BDF` to be `6XX` so `X` will be `3`. Finally, the solution I arrive here is `1 9 9 3` + `1 3` = `2 0 0 6`.

*Nb. To be honest, I don't exactly know what is the definition of canonical age.*

Comment: Nice one, i'm sry for that misuse of "canonical", in french it means rather old.